# Facebook Api Javascript - Multiple Looping not working

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm making a facebook app where to get the link user of the group members (*like this* : "**https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/536994703068744/**"

but my code doesn't work, getting error  "**property length undefined**"

here my code :

```
    function getUserLink() {            
            FB.api('/243031772570397/members',{limit:5}, function(response) {
                for(i=0;i<response.data.length; i++) {
                        var uid = response.data[i].id;
                        FB.api('/'+uid+'/', function(response2) {
                            for(y=0;y<response2.data.length; y++) {                         
                                console.log(response2.data[y].link); 
                            }
                        }); 
                }
            });
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response2 has only one record.

changinging it to below should work.

```
FB.api('/'+uid+'/', function(response2) {

                            console.log(response2.link); 

                    });
```